How to open VS with /noscale parameter when double-clic on .sln?
I have the startmenu changed in a way that the shortcut to open VS is using the /noscale parameter.
However when I open a project by a double-clic on the .sln, VS opens per default without the parameter.
Can this be managed ?
Thanks...

Visual Studio does not use the /noscale parameter by default. You can try modifying the default program associated with .sln files. Typically, .sln files are associated with the Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector, but sometimes they may be associated directly to a specific version of Visual Studio. You can follow these steps:

Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Default Programs -> Choose default apps by file type -> .sln file type, check whether its associated default program is "Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector". If not, you can change it.
If you have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed on your system, make sure the .sln file is associated with the version selector so that it opens the correct Visual Studio based on the version specified in the .sln file.
Alternatively, you can try creating a batch file or shortcut, include the /noscale parameter in it, and then open the .sln file through this batch file or shortcut.


Hi Cody
Option 1 & 2 does not apply because the project opens in VS correctly.
Option 3 is a way to do it but SLN-icons will be messed-up.

I want to confirm with you: How did you set the VS shortcut to use the /noscale parameter? Is it in its Properties that the /noscale parameter is added after the corresponding devenv.exe path in the Target?

Hi, I did it in the Startmenu shortcut. When I open VS (with the startmenu shortcut) it points to the target where I added as :"C:.....\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe" /noscale.
So if I want to open a solution with the noscale-option, I MUST pass trough the start-menu.

Your question is a bit tricky and I suggest you upload this issue on DC for help: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/home
